# CLI commands not working

Tags: magento2, cli

Yesterday I tried to install a new module in a Magento 2 app and then I ran the `di:compile` command via CLI I got the `"Fatal error: Out of memory"` error. The problem is that after that no matter what command I run the system doesn't even start to run the command, it immediately throws the exact same error. I change the **php.ini** settings and tried to run the commands using the `-dmemory_limit` directive but it always returns the same exact error in the same class

**Example:**

```
 []$ php -dmemory_limit=-1 bin/magento di:compile

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65536 bytes) in /**/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/ModuleEvent.php on line 95
```

Comment: Where was this command run -> on a local computer / dev server / server in the cloud?

Comment: was in the hosting server

Comment: I edited the question and added an example of what happens when I execute any comand

Comment: what did you change `memory_limit` to?  The Magento 2 recommended setting?  Also did you restart PHP afterwards?

Comment: Try php -dmemory_limit=3G bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Try with sudo command if you are on linux system.